# Can't use Ms ADO, give error class not registered

Tags: c++, com, runtime-error, ado

I'm using ADO in my work machine it is fine, at my machine I'm testing some ADO code after creating the application and just defined the connection and tried to run the application it fail and give me the following error **REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG** *Class not registered*. I build and run on the same machine, I use visual studio 2013, I'm on windows 7 x64 sp1.

this is my simple code

```
#include <iostream>
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll" \
    no_namespace rename("EOF", "EndOfFile")
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    _ConnectionPtr  pConnection;
    HRESULT hr;
    if(FAILED(CoInitialize(NULL)))
    {
        cout << "failed to initialize COM" << endl;
        goto end;
    }

    //      Intialize the ADO Connection object
    if(FAILED(hr = pConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection))))
    {
        cout << "failed to create connection" << endl;
        goto end;
    }
end:
    system("pause");

}
```

After a search I found some info about windows 7 sp1 non compatibility with downlevel OS  like in this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2011/10/03/yes-we-made-a-mistake-and-are-finally-going-to-fix-it.aspx) but this is different I build on win7 x64 sp1 I debug on it not lower version windows, however I installed the update hotfix `Windows6.1-KB983246-v4-x64.msu`. I don't know what is the problem, This is so bad I need help.

## Edit

This application is x86 so I use this path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll"
I tried another x64 application and I changed the path to "C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll", I worked and also worked with the path of x86

I tried the x64 path with x86, but noway it always say the class is not registered.

another thing that look so interesting is that the application is x86 but it loads x64 dlls, symbols loadded are from syswow64 not from system32 like in the following screen-shoot for the VS debugger
[image]
but after search this is normal as system32 contains 64 dlls and syswow64 contains 32 dlls

Comment: Is ADO actually registered?  If you run regsvr32 on "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll", does it start working?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but try `#import "C:\\program files\\common files\\system\\ado\\msado15.dll" rename("EOF", "EndOfFile")`.

Comment: @EricBrown : really I tried regsvr32 in system32 and that in syswow64 and for both files in prgram files (x86) and program files, I always say that it was registered successfully, and the problem is still.

Comment: @jliv902 : I tried every thing I can like what you mentioned, look at my question I added a edit part with more info.